# How to drag and drop on antd tree table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

[antd tree table](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand-children)

I want to drag and drop a row of data, but I don't know the process.

Comment: maybe antd have no drag and drop. You can do this directly on react

Answer (score 3):

Here are the examples for what you need.

```
Rows:      https://codepen.io/raisezhang/pen/MmjypX

Columns:   https://codepen.io/raisezhang/pen/MoMoyz
```